# Making sure I interpreted my rma.mv output correctly (metafor)

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I'm looking at investigating whether a tag in a fish is retained within the body (or not) and the factors that are likely driving this effect as part of a metanalysis. This includes the size of the surgical incision, the tag mass to fish mass ratio, and various other tag dimensional parameters. The response variable is the proportion of fish in a given population that have retained their tags (e.g. 0 to 1, 1 being 100% of tags retained). I then tabulated effect sizes and the corresponding variances. Because my data has a lot of 100% retention rates (ie no tags shed), I went with a Freeman-Tukey double arcsine transformed proportion. Those data were then fit to a mixed effects model (rma.mv) which included the random effect of paper ID and several fixed effects.

I back calculated an I^2 value to yield 96%.

So based on the output below and my I^2 value, I would conclude that I have high heterogeneity among studies with 96.3% of the total variance explained by study heterogeneity. With respect to the covariates, only tag to body weigh ratio had an effect on the probability of loosing a tag in the experiment such that increasing tag-BW ratios corresponded with an increased likelihood of shedding a tag. I'm also confused a bit by units as the lack of ability to back transform the values to something 'normal' is throwing me off a bit in the interpretation of model estimates and the corresponding values.

Just wondering if the above sounds correct as I have little experience using this package and analysis toolset.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

````
###transforming the data

Tag_retention_DF<-  escalc(measure = "PFT", ni=sample_size_n, 
                xi=tags_retained, 
                data =Tagged_fish_DF.1, add = 0)

###Model for factors affecting tag retention

Reten_model_full <- rma.mv(yi, vi,mods = ~tag_length+tag_diam+incision_size+exp_duration+tag_BW_ratio, 
                           random = ~1|paper_id, method = "REML", data = Tag_retention_DF)

###Model results:



# 
# Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 42; method: REML)
# 
# Variance Components:
#   
#             estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed    factor 
# sigma^2    0.0579  0.2407     22     no  paper_id 
# 
# Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
#   QE(df = 36) = 304.5762, p-val < .0001
# 
# Test of Moderators (coefficients 2:6):
#   QM(df = 5) = 17.7772, p-val = 0.0032
# 
# Model Results:
#   
#                 estimate    se     zval    pval    ci.lb    ci.ub     
# intrcpt          1.3846  0.1333  10.3837  <.0001   1.1233   1.6460  *** 
# tag_length      -0.0064  0.0048  -1.3217  0.1863  -0.0158   0.0031      
# tag_diam        -0.0079  0.0164  -0.4833  0.6289  -0.0402   0.0243      
# incision_size    0.0135  0.0090   1.5053  0.1323  -0.0041   0.0311      
# exp_duration    -0.0003  0.0005  -0.4958  0.6200  -0.0013   0.0007      
# tag_BW_ratio    -2.5181  1.0117  -2.4891  0.0128  -4.5009  -0.5353    * 
#   
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1



###calcuation of I^2 from sigma^2

W <- diag(1/Reten_model_full$vi) %>% print()
X <- model.matrix(Reten_model_full) %>% print()
P <- W - W %*% X %*% solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% W
100 * sum(Reten_model_full$sigma2) / (sum(Reten_model_full$sigma2) + (Reten_model_full$k-Reten_model_full$p)/sum(diag(P)))

####I^2 value:

#[1] 96.30036

```
````

Comment: Fitting five moderators with 42 observations was quite optimistic. High heterogeneity might be expected if the individual studies ae very precisely estimated. More importantly you do not explain why you have multiple estimates within papers. I suspect you need to account for that in some way. Have you looked at the examples in http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses in the section on multi-level meta-analysis?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! My apologies, the reason why some papers have multiple estimates stems from the study either using the same tag on multiple species (e.g. trout, salmon, bass etc) or that they've used different tag types but on the same species. I had thought to either nest species or experiment number within the paper ID, but wasn't exactly how the model would be interpreting that. The end result of that was the same trends in the data but with different output. If you have any suggests on what would be most appropriate, I'd appreciate the input!